# Suppressing "Could not change permissions" message after copying a file to NTFS Partition in Linux

Tags: linux, ntfs, file-transfer, opensuse

If I try to copy a file onto a NTFS partition in Linux, I get a warning message `Could not change permissions for <file-name>`. Is there any way to suppress this message ? I can live with this message while I copy the files in terminal, but when transferring from Dolphin a modal dialog box is shown and it gets pretty irritating.

I'm using openSUSE 11.2, on KDE 4.4 RC.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `silent` option in the /etc/fstab for the partition you are trying to copy to.

For more information on how to use `silent` have a look at http://man.linux-ntfs.org/ntfsmount.8.html

Comment: Manish, I had a look at the man pages, it says silent option is enabled by default. I explicitly passed the silent option, and still the message pops up.

Comment: I can confirm that after replacing `default_permissions` for `silent` in `/etc/fstab` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

edit fstab and change this portion of the windows line:

`user,users,gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002,umask=002,locale=en_US.UTF-8`

to this

`defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8`

http://forums.opensuse.org/applications/434289-permission-error-when-writing-ntfs-dolphin.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
/dev/sda6      /mnt/sda6       ntfs-3g defaults,silent,locale=en_US.utf8,auto,rw,allow_other,umask=000,gid=users,user,nls=utf8,exe 1     0
```

to

```
/dev/sda6       /mnt/sda6       ntfs-3g         defaults,locale=en_US.utf8      1       0*
```

No more dolphin messages! Vector Linux 6.0 SoHo.